# Find $\lim_{(x, y)\to(1, 1)}\frac{x^y-y(x-1)-1}{(x-1)^2 + (y-1)^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

$\lim_{(x, y)\to(1, 1)}\frac{x^y-y(x-1)-1}{(x-1)^2 + (y-1)^2}$

I am trying to use squeeze theorem but I am having trouble with finding an upper bounding convergent to 0 (I believe that 0 is the limit).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Taylor shows

$$x^y= 1+ y(x-1) +y(y-1)c^{y-2}(x-1)^2/2$$

for some $c$ between $x$ and $1.$

Comment: Can you expand this in this case if both variables are changing?